# Modal View doesn't release itself after dismiss

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been facing a weird issue with dismissing a modal view.

I present a modal view like this:

```
 ResepiDetail *detail =(ResepiDetail*)[[ResepiDetail alloc]init];
 [self presentModalViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

and dismiss it like this with a back button:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

after this the view dismisses itself and goes back to the previous view, but it doesn't release itself from memory. I found it out by sending a notification message and that view received it. Additionally I tried to track the VM memory Allocation, and it seems the view is still in memory.

I'm using ARC and have the same method used for another view which works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a strong pointer in ResepiDetail that points back to the view that presents it?

Comment: you can set detail to nil at time of dismissing it like detail=nil;

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, as posted, so here's some hints on how to proceed:

A sure fire way to be *certain* your view controller hasn't been deallocated is to override dealloc and log something identifiable. You can still do that in ARC, just don't explicitly call `super`. If you don't see the log when you expect to, then you have a problem.

Assuming that you have determined that you absolutely do have a problem, then the issue becomes finding the retain cycle. If the issue is that an instance of `ResepiController` isn't being dealloc'd, then you need to look for...

1. Any code outside the `ResepiController` class that has a `strong` reference to it. For example, if your class signs up as the delegate of some other class, make sure the delegate isn't using a `strong` reference.
2. Any internal blocks that may have implicitly retained `self`. Are there any blocks anywhere in your program that may have a reference to your controller at the time that you think it should be released?